# Click an element after a particular time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, youtube-iframe-api

I have a website having youtube iframe. I want to click the replay button after the video gets over. I switched to youtube iframe and found the play button. But how can I click it after a particular time period(like after the video gets over) using selenium(python). Here the element to be clicked is always available but i need to click it only after a particular time.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='YTPlayer']"))
driver.implicitly_wait(10000)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ytp-play-button.ytp-button").click()
```

Tried Explicit wait as well but the conditions dont match.

Comment: Please add all relevant code that you wrote.

Comment: Can you show the explicit wait you've tried?

Comment: Please add complete code and time you need to wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object.

This is probably not what you want as your element is available all the time.

Instead you can just run time.sleep() within your code.

Like this:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='YTPlayer']"))
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ytp-play-button.ytp-button").click()
```

However instead you should try to find a condition that needs to be satisfied and then click the button instead.

Example:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='YTPlayer']"))
    while True:
      if your-condition:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ytp-play-button.ytp-button").click()
        break
      time.sleep(1)
```

You could also use Explicit Waits as described here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html